# How to set value to valuestack in jsp by using Ognl?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el, ognl

I have an action property `tree`, which is a tree of objects.

How to set the tree's sub node by using OGNL?

ps:

the tree node can be accessed in JSP EL in this way:

```
${tree_root_node.sub_node.sub_sub_node}......
```

but the JSP EL don't support set value.

I want this:

```
${tree_root_node.sub_node.sub_sub_node="some string"}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to *set* values in the JSP?

Comment: parent jsp set some values, so the included file can recieve this. pure view logic, so I think this should be down in view, not in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following OGNL expression in the Struts tag of course:

```
%{tree_root_node.sub_node.sub_sub_node='some string'}
```

Comment: must be used in struts tags?

Comment: struts tags has support for OGNL.